# insert element in the first and last part of the specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/"     title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=8">About</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=7">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is to insert a span () element inside the ul (.menu). I want to put it before the first `li` and to the the last `li` inside that `ul` (.menu). So the expected output should be this.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <span<> <!-- this is the inserted element -->
    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/"     title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=8">About</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=7">Gallery</a></li>
    </span<> <!-- this is the inserted element -->
</ul>
```

What I've tried so far is this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<span>').insertBefore('.menu li:first-child');
    $('</span>').insertBefore('.menu li:last-child');
});
```

I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: That isn't valid HTML.  A `<span>` cannot be a child of `<ul>`.

Comment: What is it you want to do with that `<span>`? Perhaps we can suggest a better method (like putting the `<span>` _outside_ the `<ul>`)

Answer (score 2):

If you really like to do so, this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').wrapInner('<span />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mG8yV/1

Answer (score 0):

add a new li at the start of the ul. ie:

```
<li id="spanli"></li>
```

then add span element in jquery:

```
$('#spanli').append("<span id='mynewspan'></span>");
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDr5e/2/

Answer (score 0):

Insert span element, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements $('.menu').

```
$('.menu').prepend($('<span>'));
```

Insert span element, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements $('.menu').

```
$('.menu').append($('<span>'));
```

Edit: more description.

Comment: Hello warnyul, please add a little bit of explanation (even in simplest terms is ok) to your answers than just giving away to code. That would help the OP and also the people who will this answer later on would know what does your code do.